# Reading the IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying echo the DB setting value for [IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server (2012).

The linked document above states

> To view the current setting for IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS, run the following query:
>
> ```
> DECLARE @IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';  
> IF ( (2 & @@OPTIONS) = 2 ) SET @IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS = 'ON';  
> SELECT @IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS AS IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS;
> ```

Is this bitwise masking operation the only way to read this value? I have SSMS 2016 installed, is there maybe a dialog that displays all of these values in a nice table?

Comment: **`DBCC useroptions`** shows some of them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most of [SET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)-able connection options do not have global constants either

```
SELECT 
    @@DATEFIRST [DATEFIRST],
    --@@DATEFORMAT [DATEFORMAT],
    --@@DEADLOCK_PRIORITY [DEADLOCK_PRIORITY],
    @@LOCK_TIMEOUT [LOCK_TIMEOUT],
    --@@CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL],
    --@@CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT [CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT],
    --@@FIPS_FLAGGER [FIPS_FLAGGER],
    --@@IDENTITY_INSERT [IDENTITY_INSERT],
    @@LANGUAGE [LANGUAGE],
    --@@OFFSETS [OFFSETS],
    --@@QUOTED_IDENTIFIER [QUOTED_IDENTIFIER],
    --@@ARITHABORT [ARITHABORT],
    --@@ARITHIGNORE [ARITHIGNORE],
    --@@FMTONLY [FMTONLY],
    --@@NOCOUNT [NOCOUNT],
    --@@NOEXEC [NOEXEC],
    --@@NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT [NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT],
    --@@PARSEONLY [PARSEONLY],
    --@@QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT [QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT],
    @@ROWCOUNT [ROWCOUNT],
    @@TEXTSIZE [TEXTSIZE]
    --@@ANSI_DEFAULTS [ANSI_DEFAULTS],
    --@@ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF [ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF],
    --@@ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON [ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON],
    --@@ANSI_NULLS [ANSI_NULLS],
    --@@ANSI_PADDING [ANSI_PADDING],
    --@@ANSI_WARNINGS [ANSI_WARNINGS],
    --@@FORCEPLAN [FORCEPLAN],
    --@@SHOWPLAN_ALL [SHOWPLAN_ALL],
    --@@SHOWPLAN_TEXT [SHOWPLAN_TEXT],
    --@@SHOWPLAN_XML [SHOWPLAN_XML],
    --@@STATISTICS IO [STATISTICS IO],
    --@@STATISTICS XML [STATISTICS XML],
    --@@STATISTICS PROFILE [STATISTICS PROFILE],
    --@@STATISTICS TIME [STATISTICS TIME],
    --@@IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS [IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS],
    --@@REMOTE_PROC_TRANSACTIONS [REMOTE_PROC_TRANSACTIONS],
    --@@TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL [TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL],
    --@@XACT_ABORT [XACT_ABORT]
```